# Elman networks Training algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, algorithms

What is the **algorithm** that is used to train an **Elman Neural Network**? and how it works? 
And what is the role of ***the context layer*** in the **Elman** model?
Thank you.

Comment: [backpropagation through time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Backpropagation through time** BPTT is the algorithm that is used to update the weights in the recurrent neural network. One of the common examples of a recurrent neural network is LSTM, Elman or Jordan nets. Backpropagation is an essential skill that you should know if you want to effectively frame sequence prediction problems for the recurrent neural network. You should also be aware of the effects of the Backpropagation Through time on the stability, the speed of the system while training the system. for more information visite
[Backpropagation through time definition in Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Backpropagation_through_time)

Comment: Done, the explanations has been added.